# How to catch an ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid error in rails/rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to catch an ActiveRecord error on Rspec: (I'm also using a factory)

Rspec

```
it "should throw an error" do
    animal = create(:animal)
    food_store = -1;
    expect(animal.update!(food_store: food_store)).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

Validator:

```
class AnimalValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.food_store < 1
      record.errors[:food_store] << "store can't be negative"
    end
  end
end
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(animal.update!(food_store: new_share)).raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: store can't be negative
```

How am I suppose to catch this activeRecord error?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your error message "store can't be negative" isn't fully accurate, since `0` is also an invalid value. Additionally, there is no need to reference `store` in the error message, since the message is on the `:food_store` key. Right now your error message will look like: "food store store can't be negative". Finally, there is already a builtin validator for this: `validates_numericality_of :food_store, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With [`raise_error`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher), you need to `expect` a block. Without a block, it'll execute the `animal.update!` code and try to pass the return value of that method call to the `expect` method as a parameter, but it can't because it's already errors out. With a block, it defers execution of the block until the `expect` tells it to run (i.e., with `yield` or similar) and it gives RSpec a chance to intercept the exception.

So, use:

```
expect { animal.update!(food_store: food_store) }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

instead

Comment: This is purposefully ignoring that the question's given use case might be better tested using a [predicate matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers), (`expect(animal).not_to be_valid` and is currently reads more like you're testing built-in rails code (that `update!` raises an exception if invalid) instead of testing your code (that animal is invalid if it has a negative)

Comment: Or alternatively, use the `allow_value` matcher: `expect(animal).to_not allow_value(-1).for(:food_store)`

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to be more specific with the exception being raised, you can compare against the exact error message,

```
expect { animal.update!(food_store: food_store) }.to raise_error("Validation failed: store can't be negative")
```

This way you can validate that the exact validation that you expect is failing, and not any other.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a potential solution, using brackets instead of brackets

```
    expect {animal.update!(food_store: food_store)}.to raise_error
```

Posting it here for not but I'm not sure if this is the best solution

Comment: It's usually a good idea to expect an specific error type to be raised. Otherwise, there might be another error inside the block (like an ArgumentError), and your test will be a false positive, because you're testing for an ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid error. The test will still pass but your code is not behaving as you expect it to.